# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ a principal ideal domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ a  principal ideal domain?

That is, is every ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ generated by a single element?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ has class number one, i.e., its ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a PID. This follows by using the Minkowski bound: we have
$$
| \text{disc}(K)| = | \text{disc}(1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4})| = 108 = 2^23^3,
$$
so that the Minkowski bound for $K$ is given by
$$
\frac{3!}{3^3}\cdot \frac{4}{\pi}\sqrt{\left|\text{disc}(K)\right|}=\frac{16\sqrt{3}}{3\pi}\sim 2.94.
$$
But because $p=2$ has the principal prime factorisation $(2)=(\sqrt[3]{2})^3$,
the class number of $K$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea what's going on in this answer. It feels like I'm reading MO. One question: What is the factorization of $(\sqrt[3]{2},3)$?

Comment: I tried my best, but this is the easiest answer, I think. It is not elementary, I know, but standard for a course in algebraic number theory. Why the downvote ?

Comment: Not my downvote. I'm just hoping for a more elementary explanation or at least some cursory discussion of how the pieces you've laid out fit together. I'm not qualified to judge the correctness of the answer, at least not yet.

Comment: "Why the downvote ?" It's not mine, but the question does not at all fit the standards of the site (at least as some see them). To answer such question is thus frowned upon (by some).

Comment: @quid I think that's not entirely fair. If one receives a downvote on one's own post, it is frustrating to not have some indication of what is wrong with the answer, so asking such questions seems perfectly reasonable (although I would try not to direct it at any one person, but more as a general entreaty "someone tell me why I am getting downvoted").

Comment: @MarioCarneiro What is not fair? And what do you want me to do about it?  I answered the question re dv, so yes I agree it is somewhat reasonable to wonder. Though IMO the answer is rather clear if one follows those aspects of the site (but some might chose not to, which is their right).

Comment: @quid Thank you for your help. I just saw that the question already was received well (in terms of upvotes), so that I did not think about any problem. But certainly, one can argue about the question. The answer is, I think, still OK. One should perhaps rather close the question instead of downvoting correct answers - but this is something for meta, I guess.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, I agree it is alright. The question has  a dv, too, and a vtc, which is why I am quite sure the dv is for "meta" reasons, not the specifics of your answer. I agree let us stop this discourse here. I only meant to offer my quick insight into the situation as you asked (without taking any pariticular position).

Comment: FWIW I just took a crash course in algebraic number theory enough to convince me that the methods are sound (although I still don't fully understand the proof of Minkowski bound). +1